# Why nuget from VSTS nuget feed wants to install the same package multiple times and throwing error?

Tags: c#, dependencies, .net-core, nuget, .net-standard

I have a REST Api implemented using Durable Function App in Azure, which uses `netstandard2.0`, and I have other class libraries in this solution also using `netstandard2.0`. One of them is contracts projects.

There is another solution where the UAT tests placed for this solution. The reason for this is that Specflow is still not available for `.Net Core`, it is available for `.Net Framework` only. Being able to test the Api I need the contracts for the Api. That is the reason I need to include the REST Api solution Contracts project (this one is `netstandard2.0`). This dependency is managed by nuget.

When I would like to install the Contracts package (using `netstandard2.0`) in Specflow project (which uses `.Net Framework 4.7.1`) I get the error below.

What I tried:

- I restarted Visual Studio a few times because I experienced that sometimes it gets crazy when .Net Core or .Net Standard projects are in use. Restarting did not help.
- I opened the project from JetBrains Rider, but it did not see the `netstandard2.0` nuget package in the repository. I believe it is due to that the project uses `.Net Framework 4.7.1` and not Net Standard 2.0
- I saw the error `Cannot create "C:\...\REST.Api.dll" because a file or directory with the same name already exists.`. So, I deleted all packages under the solution packages directory. I also deleted cache in Visual Studio. But, the next time I started Visual Studio and tried to install package the same error occurred again.
- I also tried to install package using console on my machine (nuget.exe install ...). The error is the same.

How it is possible to resolve this issue? I read that from `.Net Framework 4.6` and above and `.Net Core` it is possible to reference `.Net Standard` libraries.

```
Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'REST.Api.1.0.0-20180305-154726' with respect to project 'MasterData.Features.HttpClient', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1'

Gathering dependency information took 861.8 ms

Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'REST.Api.1.0.0-20180305-154726' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'

Resolving dependency information took 0 ms

Resolving actions to install package 'REST.Api.1.0.0-20180305-154726'

Resolved actions to install package 'REST.Api.1.0.0-20180305-154726'
  GET https://xyzrepository.visualstudio.com/_packaging/689a2aa0-1e6a-4f39-8389-250b4ad44db8/nuget/v3/flat2/REST.api/1.0.0-20180305-154726/REST.api.1.0.0-20180305-154726.nupkg

Retrieving package 'REST.Api 1.0.0-20180305-154726' from 'Sayusi Ando's Digital Library Packages'.
  OK https://xyzrepository.visualstudio.com/_packaging/689a2aa0-1e6a-4f39-8389-250b4ad44db8/nuget/v3/flat2/REST.api/1.0.0-20180305-154726/REST.api.1.0.0-20180305-154726.nupkg 2343ms

Installing REST.Api 1.0.0-20180305-154726.

Error downloading 'REST.Api.1.0.0-20180305-154726' from 'https://xyzrepository.visualstudio.com/_packaging/689a2aa0-1e6a-4f39-8389-250b4ad44db8/nuget/v3/flat2/REST.api/1.0.0-20180305-154726/REST.api.1.0.0-20180305-154726.nupkg'.

Cannot create "C:\Users\username\.nuget\packages\REST.api\1.0.0-20180305-154726\lib\netstandard2.0\REST.Api.dll" because a file or directory with the same name already exists.
  GET https://xyzrepository.visualstudio.com/_packaging/689a2aa0-1e6a-4f39-8389-250b4ad44db8/nuget/v3/flat2/REST.api/1.0.0-20180305-154726/REST.api.1.0.0-20180305-154726.nupkg
  OK https://xyzrepository.visualstudio.com/_packaging/689a2aa0-1e6a-4f39-8389-250b4ad44db8/nuget/v3/flat2/REST.api/1.0.0-20180305-154726/REST.api.1.0.0-20180305-154726.nupkg 462ms

Installing REST.Api 1.0.0-20180305-154726.

Error downloading 'REST.Api.1.0.0-20180305-154726' from 'https://xyzrepository.visualstudio.com/_packaging/689a2aa0-1e6a-4f39-8389-250b4ad44db8/nuget/v3/flat2/REST.api/1.0.0-20180305-154726/REST.api.1.0.0-20180305-154726.nupkg'.

Cannot create "C:\Users\username\.nuget\packages\REST.api\1.0.0-20180305-154726\lib\netstandard2.0\REST.Api.dll" because a file or directory with the same name already exists.
  GET https://xyzrepository.visualstudio.com/_packaging/689a2aa0-1e6a-4f39-8389-250b4ad44db8/nuget/v3/flat2/REST.api/1.0.0-20180305-154726/REST.api.1.0.0-20180305-154726.nupkg
  OK https://xyzrepository.visualstudio.com/_packaging/689a2aa0-1e6a-4f39-8389-250b4ad44db8/nuget/v3/flat2/REST.api/1.0.0-20180305-154726/REST.api.1.0.0-20180305-154726.nupkg 464ms

Installing REST.Api 1.0.0-20180305-154726.

Install failed. Rolling back...

Package 'REST.Api.1.0.0-20180305-154726' does not exist in project 'MasterData.Features.HttpClient'

Package 'REST.Api.1.0.0-20180305-154726' does not exist in folder 'C:\VSTS\REST.QA.Features\src\packages'

Executing nuget actions took 3.51 sec

Error downloading 'REST.Api.1.0.0-20180305-154726' from 'https://xyzrepository.visualstudio.com/_packaging/689a2aa0-1e6a-4f39-8389-250b4ad44db8/nuget/v3/flat2/REST.api/1.0.0-20180305-154726/REST.api.1.0.0-20180305-154726.nupkg'.
  Cannot create "C:\Users\username\.nuget\packages\REST.api\1.0.0-20180305-154726\lib\netstandard2.0\REST.Api.dll" because a file or directory with the same name already exists.

Time Elapsed: 00:00:05.5462783
```

Comment: 1, Funny! :), 2, what do you mean by have them repaired?

Comment: "Error downloading" is the problem, it isn't a problem referencing between .NET targets. (And I can confirm netstandard2.0 libraries can be referenced by either .NET Framework or .NET Core apps, I have a huge netstandard2.0 library that is used by Azure Functions v1 which is Framework, and a bunch of core-based utilities and sites.)

Comment: "a file or directory with the same name already exists"

Comment: Yep, I saw that. I deleted all nuget packages, cleared VS cache. At the next Package-Install the same error occurred again.

Comment: I'm guessing you should probably post the package definition and change your question to reflect that as the problem, then hope a NuGet ninja stops by to help.

Comment: @McGuireV10 How do you install your NetStandard package to a framework project? Install-Package does not have parameter for this. Nuget searches for project target which is in my case 4.7.1, but the library is Netstandard2.0, and nuget says there is no such package in the repository.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. I have to list as dependency group all the framework I would like to use the NetStandard2.0 package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of the problem is that the target properties conflicted with another filename. (names are shortened)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2012/06/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
      <!-- package stuff -->
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETStandard2.0" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="..." target="lib\netstandard2.0\Contracts.dll" />
    <file src="..." target="lib\netstandard2.0\Contracts.dll" />
    <file src="..." target="lib\netstandard2.0\Contracts.dll" />
  </files>
</package>
```